# Passing arguments to selector in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, selector

I'm programmatically adding a UITapGestureRecognizer to one of my views:

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(modelObj:myModelObj)))

self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

func handleTap(modelObj: Model) {
  // Doing stuff with model object here
}
```

The first problem I encountered was "Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@Objc' method, property, or initializer.

Cool, so I added @objc to the handleTap signature:

```
@objc func handleTap(modelObj: Model) {
  // Doing stuff with model object here
}
```

Now I'm getting the error "Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C.

It's just an image of the map of a building, with some pin images indicating the location of points of interest. When the user taps one of these pins I'd like to know which point of interest they tapped, and I have a model object which describes these points of interest. I use this model object to give the pin image it's coordinates on the map so I thought it would have been easy for me to just send the object to the gesture handler.

Comment: You can't pass values to a selector like that. Why can't you keep that value in an instance variable and access it from the selector method ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35635595/sending-a-parameter-argument-to-function-through-uitapgesturerecognizer-selector.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

It looks like you're misunderstanding a couple of things.

When using [target/action](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html), the function signature has to have a certain form…

```
func doSomething()
```

or

```
func doSomething(sender: Any)
```

or

```
func doSomething(sender: Any, forEvent event: UIEvent)
```

where…

> The `sender` parameter is the control object sending the action message.

In your case, the sender is the `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Also, `#selector()` should contain the func signature, and does NOT include passed parameters. So for…

```
func handleTap(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    
}
```

you should have…

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(sender:)))
```

Assuming the func and the gesture are within a view controller, of which `modelObj` is a property / ivar, there's no need to pass it with the gesture recogniser, you can just refer to it in `handleTap`

Comment: [The Target-Action Mechanism](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol#1658488) section of the [UIControl documentation for Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol) is also a good read showing the three forms action methods can take.

Comment: To add to this great answer, certain object types such as Timer have `userInfo: Any?` parameters that can be used in conjunction with this solution to pass in model objects with the sender.

Comment: @JustinVallely  this really makes it a great answer! thank you! :)

Comment: Not a good answer. You didn't explain how sender can be used

Answer (score 42):

Step 1: create the custom object of the sender.

step 2: add properties you want to change in that a **custom object** of the sender

step 3: typecast the sender in receiving function to a **custom object** and access those properties

For eg:
on click of the button if you want to send the string or any custom object then

step 1: create

```
class CustomButton : UIButton {

    var name : String = ""
    var customObject : Any? = nil
    var customObject2 : Any? = nil

    convenience init(name: String, object: Any) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
        self.customObject = object
    }
}
```

step 2-a: set the custom class in the storyboard as well

[image]

step 2-b: Create IBOutlet of that button with a custom class as follows

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnFullRemote: CustomButton!
```

step 3: add properties you want to change in that a **custom object** of the sender

```
btnFullRemote.name = "Nik"
btnFullRemote.customObject = customObject
btnFullRemote.customObject2 = customObject2
btnFullRemote.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnFullRemote(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

step 4: typecast the sender in receiving function to a **custom object** and access those properties

```
@objc public func btnFullRemote(_ sender: Any) {

var name : String = (sender as! CustomButton).name as? String

var customObject : customObject = (sender as! CustomButton).customObject as? customObject

var customObject2 : customObject2 = (sender as! CustomButton).customObject2 as? customObject2

}
```

Comment: Clever answer that gives a good solution (rather than saying it's impossible, as most answers I have found about this say)... Tried this approach and can confirm it works

Comment: Custom object wrapper to pass everything you need! So clever. Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

Swift 5.0 iOS 13

I concur a great answer by [Ninad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4792027/ninad-kambli). Here is my 2 cents, the same and yet different technique; a minimal version.

Create a custom class, throw a enum to keep/make the code as maintainable as possible.

```
enum Vs: String {
  case pulse = "pulse"
  case precision = "precision"
} 

class customTap: UITapGestureRecognizer {
  var cutomTag: String?
}
```

Use it, making sure you set the custom variable into the bargin. Using a simple label here, note the last line, important labels are not normally interactive.

```
let precisionTap = customTap(target: self, action: #selector(VC.actionB(sender:)))
precisionTap.customTag = Vs.precision.rawValue
precisionLabel.addGestureRecognizer(precisionTap)
precisionLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

And setup the action using it, note I wanted to use the pure enum, but it isn't supported by Objective C, so we go with a basic type, String in this case.

```
@objc func actionB(sender: Any) {
// important to cast your sender to your cuatom class so you can extract your special setting.
  let tag = customTag as? customTap
  switch tag?.sender {
    case Vs.pulse.rawValue:
      // code
    case Vs.precision.rawValue:
      // code
    default:
      break
    }
}
```

And there you have it.

Comment: Awesome. this works. But I think it should be corrected that 
@objc func actionB(sender: Any) {
   let tap = sender as? customTap
   switch tap?.customTag { ...

Answer (score 10):

```
cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row //setting tag
cell.btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showAlert(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)

@objc func showAlert(_ sender: UIButton){
  print("sender.tag is : \(sender.tag)")// getting tag's value
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just create a custom class of UITapGestureRecognizer =>

```
import UIKit

class OtherUserProfileTapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer {

    let userModel: OtherUserModel    
    init(target: AnyObject, action: Selector, userModel: OtherUserModel) {
        self.userModel = userModel
        super.init(target: target, action: action)
    }
}
```

And then create UIImageView extension =>

```
import UIKit

    extension UIImageView {
    
        func gotoOtherUserProfile(otherUserModel: OtherUserModel) {
            isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            let gestureRecognizer = OtherUserProfileTapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didTapOtherUserImage(_:)), otherUserModel: otherUserModel)
            addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
        }
        
        @objc internal func didTapOtherUserImage(_ recognizer: OtherUserProfileTapGestureRecognizer) {
            Router.shared.gotoOtherUserProfile(otherUserModel: recognizer.otherUserModel)
        }
    }
```

Now use it like =>

```
self.userImageView.gotoOtherUserProfile(otherUserModel: OtherUserModel)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `UIAction` instead:

```swift
self.imageView.addAction(UIAction(identifier: UIAction.Identifier("imageClick")) { [weak self] action in
    self?.handleTap(modelObj)
}, for: .touchUpInside)
```