# Pass function argument into selector in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parameter-passing, selector, uitoolbar

I have five pickers in total. I want to create a done button for each one of them. I want to use a different selector for each one to to do different actions. To set up the done buttons I was trying to use the same method for all of them, but I do not know how to pass a function argument into the selector in Swift.

```
func createDoneButton(txtField: UITextField, donePressed: /* What do I need here? */) {
    let toolbar = UIToolbar() // create toolbar
    toolbar.sizeToFit() // toolbar fits the size of the screen
        
    let doneBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed)) // action when the done button was pressed
    toolbar.setItems([doneBtn], animated: true)
    txtField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
}
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43251708/passing-arguments-to-selector-in-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43251708/passing-arguments-to-selector-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer in your question :)
Simply use `Selector` parameter type, and no need `#selector()`

```
    func createDoneButton(txtField: UITextField, donePressed: Selector){
        let toolbar = UIToolbar() // create toolbar
        toolbar.sizeToFit() // toolbar fits the size of the screen

        let doneBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: donePressed) // action when the done button was pressed
        toolbar.setItems([doneBtn], animated: true)
        txtField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
}
```